# Slice sampling in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a question on the algorithm **slice sampling in MATLAB** (`slicesample`).

Consider a random variable, `g(X)`, with un-normalised pdf `f:=1(g(X)=g)` where `g` is a real number.

Suppose I compute `g(X)` in an ancillary function, `@dens_slice`, for any given value `x` of `X`.

Let `starting` be a value `x` of `X` such that `g(X)=g`.

Then I set

```
slicesample(starting,num,'pdf',@dens_slice);
```

with `num=2000` denoting the input `nsamples`.

Suppose I save all the evaluation of `g(X)` made by the algorithm in a column vector `A`. After a while the algorithm stops and `A` is composed by much more than `2000` values.

Does `2000` correspond to the number of values in `A` equal to `g`?

---

Example:

```
%%%%%%MAIN%%%%%%%
clear all
%Set slice sampling

rng('default');

rng(1);

global U
U = randn(2, 1);
S_init = U(1)*3 + U(2)*2;

global starting
starting = [S_init 3 2];

global iteration
iteration = 0;

global resultslice
resultslice = [starting(1), iteration, starting(2:end)]; % For each row: obj.func, iteration, parameter values
save('resultslice.mat', 'resultslice')

num = 100;
param = slicesample(starting(2:end), num, 'pdf', @dens_slice);

exit


%%%%DENS_SLICE%%%%%
function ind = dens_slice(param)
    global starting
    global resultslice
    global iteration
    global U

    S = criterion_slice(param);
    ind = 1.*(S==starting(1));

    iteration = iteration + 1;  % Update iteration

    resultslice = [resultslice;[S iteration param]];  %update result
    save('resultslice.mat', 'resultslice')
end


%%%%CRITERION_SLICE%%%%%
function S = criterion_slice(param)
    global U
    beta1 = param(1);
    beta2 = param(2);
    S = beta1*U(1) + beta2*U(2);
end
```

In the example above `A` is the first column of `resultslice`.

Comment: Iteration of what algorithm? Each time you call slicesample() if retrieves 'nsamples' number of samples, so in your case, each time it will return 2000 values.

Comment: Clarification: "at each iteration of the algorithm" is unclear. I meant "at each evaluation of X" made by the algorithm.

Comment: I have clarified my question. Is it clearer now?

Comment: I ran the code on a simple PDF and the function returned 2000 values. Would you mind posting a simplified example of your code so I can run it and see what the problem is? You should only be getting 2000 values back, from what I understand.

Comment: My code looks like the example above.

Comment: By simplified example, I mean please recreate the problem without copying and pasting your entire program in here. Specifically I do not have the definition of @dens_slice so I can't tell if it's a problem with the user-defined function, a bug, or just the way you are trying to use slicesample()

Comment: How would you normalize your pdf's example? (Just a side question before the next step)

Comment: I don't need normalisation for slice sampling, right? It is not an easy question but the idea is that it should be divided by the Lebesgue measure of the set collecting all the beta1,beta2 such that ind=1.

Comment: Your question sounds statistical rather than programming related since you want to understand what the "statistical" algorithm does. It also seems that you want to re-implement the slicesampling, while the function already does that for you and all you need to supply is your density.

Comment: @tex is your intention to continually update/modify the PDF function?